# Extract lotus notes mails in RFC822 using Domino.dll

Tags: c#, lotus-domino, interop-domino

I want to send my Lotus Notes mails in RFC822 format.

How can i do it using Domino.dll or any other api in c#.

Comment: my advice would be (you know what's coming, right?).....not to use Lotus Notes!! Sorry, could not resist....

Answer (score 0):

Head over to OpenNTF.org. There is a sample in LotusScript how to save Lotus Notes eMails as MIME. (Almost) everything you can do in LotusScript you can do through the COM interface of the Lotus Notes Client. However you need to have a Lotus Notes client installed properly. An alternative would be to use that LotusScript sample code to write an Lotus Domino agent to render the result through a web service on Domino. Then your application could just call the web service to get converted messages.
You need to be clear that it only makes sense for standard eMails, but neither applications nor messages with constructs not supported by mime like encrypted messages, signatures, sections, OLE objects etc.
An alternative could be the export into XML format which is also supported on Domino.

Or you could just upgrade to the latest version and happily use it on Windows, Linux and Mac (I work for IBM, so I had to say that) :-)